# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo?android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #265: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

I have error at this  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Please help to resolve

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.kidsfun/com.example.admin.kidsfun.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #265: Error
>   inflating class 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

xml code  when trying to open that app it showing error unfortunately app is stopped please check it other app are working properly only this app getting error

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnA"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/a" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnb"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/btnc"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/c"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:id="@+id/btnd"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/d"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="E"
            android:id="@+id/btne"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/e"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="F"
            android:id="@+id/btnf"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/f"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="G"
            android:id="@+id/btng"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/g"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="H"
            android:id="@+id/btnh"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/h"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="I"
            android:id="@+id/btni"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/i"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="J"
            android:id="@+id/btnj"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/i"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="K"
            android:id="@+id/btnk"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/k"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:id="@+id/btnl"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/l"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="M"
            android:id="@+id/btnm"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/m"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="N"
            android:id="@+id/btnn"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/n"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="O"
            android:id="@+id/btno"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/o"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="P"
            android:id="@+id/btnp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/p"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="Q"
            android:id="@+id/btnq"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/q"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="R"
            android:id="@+id/btnr"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/r"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="S"
            android:id="@+id/btns"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="T"
            android:id="@+id/btnt"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/t"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="U"
            android:id="@+id/btnu"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/u"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="V"
            android:id="@+id/btnv"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/v"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="W"
            android:id="@+id/btnw"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/w"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="X"
            android:id="@+id/btnx"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/x"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="Y"
            android:id="@+id/btny"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/y"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="Z"
            android:id="@+id/btnz"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/z"
            android:textSize="70dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Change your first LinearLayout attributes to this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Notice the layout_height is now "wrap_content"

Comment: after changing this error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError